# Xamarin Forms Switch inside Stacklayout BindableLayout get toggled event using MVVM (Prism.Forms)

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I have the following list:

```
 <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding NotificationList}" Margin="0,10,0,10" >
                     <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>                             <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource StacklayoutAStyle}">
                                <Label Text="{Binding notificationLabel}" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                 <Switch IsToggled="{Binding isNotificationToggled, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" />
                             </StackLayout>
                         </DataTemplate>
                     </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                 </StackLayout>
```

I'd like to get the notificationLabel text when I toggle the corresponding switch in the list. My ViewModel looks like this:

```
 private ObservableCollection<NotificationModel> _notificationList = new ObservableCollection<NotificationModel>
         {
             new NotificationModel { notificationLabel = "Notification1", isNotificationToggled = true },
             new NotificationModel { notificationLabel = "Notification2", isNotificationToggled = false },
             new NotificationModel { notificationLabel = "Notification3", isNotificationToggled = false },
             new NotificationModel { notificationLabel = "Notification4", isNotificationToggled = true },
         };
         public ObservableCollection<NotificationModel> NotificationList
         {
             get { return _notificationList; }
             set { SetProperty(ref _notificationList, value); }
         }
```

When I toggled Notification 3 for example, it switches to on (true), but how can I capture that event with "Notification 3"?

Comment: You need to add code in `NotificationModel`'s `isNotificationToggled setter`, to do whatever you want. If `isNotificationToggled` is currently an "auto property", then convert it to a "full property" (which has explicit "get" and "set" methods). Then add code inside "set".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Switch.Toggled` to listen for toggled event,then get the BindingContext (`NotificationModel`),then determine which Switch is turned on according to `NotificationModel.notificationLabel`.

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding NotificationList}" Margin="0,10,0,10" >
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>                             
                 <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource StacklayoutAStyle}">
                       <Label Text="{Binding notificationLabel}" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                       <Switch IsToggled="{Binding isNotificationToggled, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" Toggled="Switch_Toggled" />
                 </StackLayout>
             </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

in your page.xaml.cs:

```
private void Switch_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
        Switch sw = sender as Switch;
        NotificationModel notificationModel = (NotificationModel)sw.BindingContext;
        if (e.Value)
        {
            switch (notificationModel.notificationLabel)
            {
                case "Notification1":
                    //do something
                    break;

                case "Notification2":
                    //do something
                    break;
                case "Notification3":
                    //do something
                    break;
                case "Notification4":
                    //do something
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```